# Необработанное исключение по адресу 0x51A0348A (ucrtbased.dll) в TEST.exe: 0xC0000005: нарушение прав доступа при чтении по адресу 0x00002564

Tags: c

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main()
{
    char str[100];
    int count = 0;
    int l;

    for ( l= 0; (str[l] = getchar()) != '\n'; l++);
    str[l] = '\0';

    for (int i = 0; str[i] != '\0'; i++)
    {
        for (i; str[i] == ' '; i++)
            ;
        int a = 0;
        if (str[i] != ' ')
        {
            a = i;
        }

        for (i; str[i] != ' '; i++)
            ;
        int b = i - 1;
        int flag = 0;
        for (int j = a, k = b; j < (k + j) / 2; j++, k--)
        {
            if (str[j] == str[k])
            {
                flag = 1;
            }
            else
                flag = 0;

        }
        if (flag == 1)
            count++;
    }
    printf('%d', count);

    return 0;

}
```

Comment: просто посмотрите на эти две строки `for (int i = 0; str[i] != '\0'; i++)
    {
        for (i; str[i] == ' '; i++)
            ;` логично, что внутренний цикл быстро выходит за пределы строки (если нет пробела) и все... дальше программа в разнос. Что именно делает Ваша программа?

Comment: Находит количество полиндромов в строке